# Application that lets user create form

Tags: ios, swift, class, oop

I'm creating a registration form application. Users of the application will be able to add and delete questions.

So basically I have a class called questions and the methods for "modifying" questions will go under it. Right now I am working on the methods for adding a question to the form.

A question will consist of:

- `UILabel` (What is your name?)
- `UITextField` or `UISegmentedControl`
  (Used for multiple choice question)

I am very new to Swift and still what I would consider a beginner at object-oriented programming. Right now I am trying to design the Questions class layout, should it look something like this?

```
class Question {
      var label: UILabel
      var multiChoice: UISegmentedControl
      var textInput: UITextField

      init(label: UILabel, multiChoice: UISegmentedControl, textInput: UITextField) {
             self.label = label
             self.multiChoice = multiChoice
             self.textInput = textInput
      }

      // methods for adding question
}
```

So obviously the composition of a question will depend on actions (buttons pushed) the user takes. When a user selects to add a new question they will input a label, and decide whether they want to use a segmented control or text field.

Here's where my question comes in. After the user has decided on the parameters, my method for adding a question should create a new instance of a Question, which will be returned. This new instance of a Question should then be added to an array that stores all the created questions. Would this array be initialized in the action (pressing the add question button) or should it be initialized globally, so all future methods I add can access it.

Answer (score 0):

The fewer global variables, the better.

Given the class above, I would expect your method for creating a `Question` will be a method of some UIViewController subclass and the array containing all the Questions should be a property of that same view controller sub-class.

The method that creates questions will have to add the label, segmentedControl and textInputs to some UIView (possibly the view controller's main view) so they can be visible.

Another quick note... If a Question can be *either* text input *or* multiple choice, but not both, then this one class should not have both fields in it. You will need two `Question` sub-classes (`FillInQuestion` and `MultiChoiceQuestion` perhaps,) possibly both derived from a `Question` base class.